# Create page excerpts for landinpage

Tags: pages, excerpt

Forgive my ignorance in wordpress, but I'm not finding the information I am looking for.

What I am trying to do is (on an existing site) remove dropdowns from navigation by creating landing pages. In example for `about` in the navigation instead of having a drop down (`about > founding` in example) when the user clicks on about they should be going to a landing page. This landing page would have excerpts of the pages that were links in the dropdown nav originally. In example, there would be a featured image, the excerpt and a read more link to the page `founding` in the above example. The challenge I am having is gathering the excerpt of a page and linking to it (via the read more link), and I'd like to avoid converting it to a post if at all possible.

I'd also love help figuring out how to grab the featured image but believe I could discover that on my own.

Comment: Are the pages hierarchical? Meaning, is 'founding' a child of the 'about' page?

Comment: yes, exactly. I'm trying to remove the hierarchy from navigation, and instead reflect it on the parent about page, with a linked excerpt for each 'child' if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an array of child pages using [get_children](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children). Use the parent page's ID as `post_parent`.

Once you have the array, you can loop through them and display whatever info you want. For example, to show the page title (linked) and the excerpt you could do:

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post -> ID
);
$children = get_children( $args );

if( $children ):
    foreach( $children as $child ):
        $permalink = get_permalink( $child -> ID );
        echo '<a href="' . $permalink . '">' . $child -> post_title . '</a>';
        echo $child -> post_excerpt
    endforeach;
endif;
```

You mentioned using the read more link - that's actually added to the post content, not the excerpt.

### How to use 'Read More' - create a loop

Get the children as above but create a loop from the results. Using `the_content()` will show the truncated content where you have added a 'Read More' marker. Do this instead of the `if` statement above.

```
foreach ( $children as $child ) : setup_postdata( $child );
  the_content();
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

You can see more examples on the [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) page

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it certainly seems we are going in the right direction, the issue I see here is that it is written for posts where I am using custom pages as the children and that is what has me caught up

Comment: nope, this is for pages. If you're using a custom post type, then just specify that in the get_children $args: `'post_type'   => 'custom_post_type'`. (Post can't have children - they're non-hierarchical)

Comment: awesome, let me give it a shot then

Comment: this is working to some extent but it is not creating the excerpt, it is creating links out of all the titles of the children however. All the children are pages, some of which are made with custom unique custom templates. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps there's a mis-understanding of the Wordpress terminology, the excerpt is a manually added summary of the article, while 'Read More' placed in the content. I've updated the answer to include 'Read More'

Comment: It did not work completely, but i doubt im going to get a fix on here.

Comment: What isn't working? If you can give some more info I'll try and help

Comment: "this is working to some extent but it is not creating the excerpt, it is creating links out of all the titles of the children however. All the children are pages, some of which are made with custom unique custom templates. Any ideas?" 

I've gone about it a completely different way at this point though, thank you

Comment: Please see the update I posted in the answer, from "How to use 'Read More' - create a loop". The excerpt is hand-written, to use 'Read More' you need to add it to the _content_ of the page.

Comment: Read more is not an excerpt though, an excerpt would be a snippet of text from the page's text, a preview of what the text is.

Comment: No, that's what the read more functionality is used for. An excerpt is hand-written. See the excerpt box at the bottom of post pages.

Comment: I fail to see the logic behind a read _more_ button if they didn't read anything to begin with, but regardless, I've marked this task as complete, and am sure I am not going to get to a solution on this. I can't imagine being forced to hand-populate anything on a CMS as I think it defeats the purpose. I'd much rather organically code a dynamic page than deal with a CMS only to find that I have to hand populate ever-changing previews of pages. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: You're not forced to hand-populate...simply there are 2 options: 1) Add a read more link to the page content to it cuts where you want (http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Read-More-to-Wordpress) or 2) Write an excerpt if you want it to be different from the opening paragraph(s) of your post.

Of course, you could use a filter that would trim your content to automatically show the first paragraph of your content without the need for read more.

But that's a different question ;)

Comment: That would be the same question as that first paragraph would be an excerpt. It wouldn't be a requirement for it to be the first paragraph, but the first paragraph would satisfy the need for an excerpt.